# Android: How can I get ip address from an android app?

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to get the ip address from android app?

Comment: Check out this blog post: http://www.droidnova.com/get-the-ip-address-of-your-device,304.html

Answer (score 3):

I kept this in my bookmark for some time, but never got to test it:

http://www.droidnova.com/get-the-ip-address-of-your-device,304.html

```
public String getLocalIpAddress() {
    try {
        for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
            NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
            for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
                InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) {
                    return inetAddress.getHostAddress().toString();
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (SocketException ex) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, ex.toString());
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: You can also edit the return clauses in order to return all values and not just the first one. Trivial work, of course. No big deal.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a tether app for your Android data connection, then use the tether to connect to PC. Find the ad hoc connection and connect. Then right click and select status. This will give you the phone's IP address. I use the Android app "Barnicle WiFi tether" and am using a Windows 7 PC.