# Android HotSpot Listening Socket

Tags: android

My app opens an http socket to accept some files from user's browser, so it needs WiFi ON for that. What I think would be cool if the app could continue doing that in WiFi HotSpot mode (tethering?) however I can't obtain the Android's IP address to start listening on. Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

I was doing similar task. When enabling HotSpot and you ask Android what's your IP, you'll get the IP address given from 3G network (if you are getting IP address with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4157992/1297504) code, it seems the last network interface interrogated is 3G, and this is the value returned by the function).

That IP address from 3G interface will work anyways: your Wifi client will connect to your device because Android is acting as a "bridge" (from Wifi to 3G) and the 3G-interface will be visible from your Wifi client.